# YARP - Change route matching configs at runtime

Tags: reverse-proxy, gateway, ms-yarp

I have the following route config for an Angular SSR node app:

```json
"angular-route": {
  "ClusterId": "angular",
  "CorsPolicy": "default",
  "Match": {
    "Path": "{**catch-all}",
    "Headers": [
      {
        "Name": "host",
        ...
      },
      {
        "Name": "user-agent",
        "Values": [ "Googlebot", "Storebot-Google", ... ],
        "Mode": "Contains"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

which allows only search engine requests to be selected. Other non-SEO requests will reach the `app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html")` and will fetch the Angular client bundle.

Is there a way that I can enable/disable that `user-agent` rule on runtime? Currently I have to change it and republish.